# How to create strings in Python

Tags: python, numbers

I wanted to write a little program, just to test some numbers, but for that I have to turn a random number, 240812 for example, in single numbers, like, 2, then 4, and 0 and so on, but not in a list, like a single string for every digit in the given number, the number has to be long as I want, from 1 digit to theoratically 1 billion or more digits. So how do I say the program to create a new string for every digit?

Comment: Did you mean `str(240812)`?

Comment: `list(str(240812))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, I think the below code may be what you are after:

```
def numstr_creator(rand_number):
    '''function to turn any number of any size into individual 
       strings by looping through with 'for':
    '''
    rand_number = str(rand_number) # convert to string
    for num in rand_number: # for every number in string:
        print(num, type(num)) # print each number and the type of number


numstr_creator(123456789) # Call function with any number
```

Terminal Output:

```
1 <class 'str'>
2 <class 'str'>
3 <class 'str'>
4 <class 'str'>
5 <class 'str'>
6 <class 'str'>
7 <class 'str'>
8 <class 'str'>
9 <class 'str'>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @lemon, I've tried to be as verbose as I can by commenting each line whilst also stating the job of the function at the top. I'm new to this so would appreciate direction in which particular part you are referring to. Kind regards ,CoderMacleod

Comment: you got it nearly, i dont want the numbers to be print, i need them as single integers to calculate with them, if i have 123, i want to calculate the square root of each digit and summarize them all together to the result. this needs to be repeated until the number reaches 4 or 1 and is in a loop

Comment: Hi @agginym, I'm finding it difficult to understand your end goal as it's somewhat contradictory of your original question. Perhaps, if you do whatever calculation before converting to string, you will have the required outcome? Hope you manage to sort it out :)

Comment: Thank you @TImus for de-fluffing! I'll endeavour to achieve a more 'to the point' strategy in the future :)